# How do I get away from using the `self = this` hack when using ES6 classes and generator functions?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, co

I have tried to use the explicit .bind(this) and that did not work.  I also know arrow functions dont work here.

```js
'use strict';

const co     = require('co');

class ServiceDemo {

    constructor(repository, config, loggingService) {
        this.config = config;
        this.repository = repository;
        this.loggingService = loggingService;
    }

    checkForNotifications(pricePoint) {

        const self = this;

        return co(function*() {
            self.loggingService.debug('test');
            //const surprisesToNotify = yield this.getSomething(pricePoint);
        });
    }

    getSomething(){
        return co(function*() {
            return {};
        });
    }

}

module.exports = SurpriseSchedulerService;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

co will use the context it's called with when it calls the generator:

```
co.call( this, function*() {
    this.loggingService.debug('test');
});
```

Comment: This is the most correct answer, in regards to `co`.

Answer (score 0):

Using `.bind(this)` should work:

```js
(function() {
  return this === function*() {
    return this; // global object or undefined
  }().next().value;
}).call({}); // false :(
```

```js
(function() {
  return this === function*() {
    return this; // outer this
  }.bind(this)().next().value;
}).call({}); // true :)
```